# What is the difference between cacher and masquer?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, choix-de-mot

I am somewhat confused in regards to the verbs *cacher* and *masquer*. Both of them mean *to hide* in English, but I believe it depends on what context they are used in.

Looking through usages of the word, I see mostly masquer being used. Examples include:

- Masquer les éléments sélectionnés (Windows Explorer)
- Réseau masqué (Windows)
- Masquer les paramètres avancés... (Google Chrome)
- Masquer la section (Facebook)

However when I type `hide` into Google Translate and Bing Translator, *cacher* is the first word that comes up. To me, it seems that *masquer* is "to mask, to hide visually", whereas *cacher* means "to conceal, to store away".

What are the differences in meaning? Examples to provide context would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd say the intent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although *cacher* can usually be used in constructions similar to *masquer*, the reverse is not quite true, because *masquer* has an additional semantic or metaphoric implication of hiding by covering up with or behind something else, whereas *cacher* also encompass the idea of hiding somewhere, which masquer cannot be used for.

In the informatics domain, both it and *hide* carry a meaning that they never (nor did *cacher*) did previously: "make invisible". I don't believe there is any strong semantic reason for one to be chosen over the other, it's one of those usages that just... happen, so to say.

Comment: Well, “*cacher*” often has the sense that you don’t want what your « cacher » to be found. Moreover, there is a risk of confusion with “cache” as in fast duplicate memory.

Comment: The second paragraph is a little hard to understand. "Both it and hide". Who is "it" here? The verb "masquer" ? I am not sure if "masquer" is more usual than "cacher" in the informatics domain or not.

Answer (score 5):

Pratiquement aujourd'hui :

« Cacher » met l'accent sur le résultat qui est de garder un secret
son synonyme littéraire est « dissimuler ».

Alors que « masquer » est plus neutre/professionnel, car met l'accent sur l'action : poser un masque. La raison n'importe pas.

Un réseau masqué est une façon neutre de dire qu'un masque a été posé. Dans le but de cacher/dissimuler le réseau !

Answer (score 2):

"Masquer" is to "hide" something by masking or covering it up.

"Cacher" is to "hide" something by "secreting" it in a "hiding place."

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure my explanation is semantically correct, but here is the difference for me :

- *Masquer* means *to hide*, but the person you are hiding it for, is perfectly aware that the thing is here, it's just not visible for him/her

Example: *Masquer son visage* : everyone know it's here, but you can't see it.

- *Cacher* means *to hide*, but the person you are hiding it for is not aware that the thing is here. You don't want him/her to find it.

Example: *Cacher un trésor* : you hide it, and you don't want people to find it.

---

So in your browser configuration, you use *masquer les paramètres avancés*, because there is a button that say *montrer les paramètres avancés*, so you know the advanced parameters are there. They are just hidden for ergonomical convenience and not to confuse users. But you want people to be able to find them.